# Class method return distinct values

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql, core-data

I have this instance method that returns a list of distinct values.

```
-(void)test
{
  return [self valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.values"];
}
```

It works for one especific object, but i have a lot of objects.

I am thinking about  a class method that returns something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s) FROM table_name
```

What is the best way to do this? And how can i have do it whith a class method?

Edit:

It works now! Thanks, AKV!

@interface

```
+(NSArray *)fetchAll; // array with all managed objects.
+(NSSet *)myMethod;
```

@implementation

```
+(NSSet *)myMethod
{
    return [NSSet setWithArray:[[MyClass fetchAll] valueForKey:@"myField"]];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how a class method would be beneficial.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a set, and find the distinct values as :

```
NSSet *distinctValues = [NSSet setWithArray:[myArrayOfCustomObjects valueForKey:@"yourKey"]];
```